# Unsigned addition in VHDL resulting in incorrect length unsigned result

Tags: arrays, vhdl, unsigned, hdl, vivado

**update**
@user1155120's comment below is correct:

> This is telling you the error is somewhere in the realm of -- other assignments here

I had multiplication operations which I mistakenly believed functioned in the same manner as addition. My mistake.

I am working on a rudimentary ALU using VHDL.

Here is the code which is throwing an error:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_misc.all;

entity alu is
  port (
    A, B : in unsigned(31 downto 0);
    sel  : in unsigned(2 downto 0);
    O    : out unsigned(63 downto 0));
end entity alu;

architecture Behavioral of alu is
begin
        O <= resize(A, 64) + resize(B, 64) when sel = "000"
        -- other assignments here
end Behavioral;
```

My understanding of Unsigned addition in VHDL is that the length of the sum will be equal to the longest length of the operands. However, my code gives the following error:

> ERROR: Array sizes do not match, left array has 64 elements, right array has 128 elements

Strange. However, if I change the resize values to be less than 64 bits, then the behavior follows my expectation (width=max width of operands). Like this:

```
        O <= resize(A, 33) + resize(B, 33) when sel = "000"
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: Array sizes do not match, left array has 64 elements, right array has 33 elements

I end up being very confused. Why is the width of the output changing when I resize only to a certain value?

I am using the student license for Vivado 2020.

Comment: Provide a [mcve], here the complete conditional signal assignment statement instead of a wavy handed comment. by adding a statement closing semicolon to the conditional signal assignment statement your code analyzes (compiles) elaborates (links and loads) and simulates successfully. (This is telling you the error is somewhere in the realm of `-- other assignments here`, provide the full and complete error message.)

Comment: `ERROR: Array sizes do not match, left array has 64 elements, right array has 128 elements` This would have occurred for the conditionally selected value `resize(A, 64) * resize(B, 64)` instead of `A * B`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Note the signal assignment to `O` is note a complete statement. Your problem can't be replicated without something syntactically correct and semantically replicates the error. To troubleshoot you can comment out the other alternatives in the conditional signal assignment one at a time, if that doesn't point to which one, two at a time, ...  While DonFusili's answer based on my comment I subsequently deleted is likely essentially correct (but likely an alternative instead of an independent assignment) it's not based on something your readers can see in your question.

Comment: Questions and answers are intended to inform future readers with the same or similar problems. When your question doesn't allow the problem to be duplicated there is no ability to learn from them.  The purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of Q & As validated through up voting when found useful. There's an emphasis on replicating results.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have

```
O <= resize(A, 64) * resize(B, 64) when sel = whatever
```

Somewhere in your code on a lower line and you're messing up the line numbers when you read the error. The moment you change the addition to be wrong, that's the first line analysis fails on and you get the error you see now.

Comment: Answers not based factually on the question are called 'guesses'. Perhaps the question shouldn't be answered as it it currently written.